# An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant acra android

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to add acra support to my app for sending reports when app crashes. I did class:

```
@ReportsCrashes(formUri = "",
        mailTo = "****@gmail.com",
        mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
        customReportContent = Array<ReportField>(5) { i: Int -> ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION },
        resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text)

class AcraReports : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        ACRA.init(this)
    }
}
```

but I can't add this line for defining data which I would like to send:

```
customReportContent = Array<ReportField>(5) { i: Int -> ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION },
```

At [this example](https://androidpedia.net/en/tutorial/1324/acra) this field is defined in such way:

```
customReportContent = { /* */ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME, ReportField.PACKAGE_NAME,ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION, ReportField.PHONE_MODEL,ReportField.LOGCAT },
```

but this code doesn't work :( What I did wrong and how to add this info to my message?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your intention behind Array(5) but this one works and you should be able to elaborate from there:

```
@ReportsCrashes(
    formUri = "",
    formKey = "the key",
    mailTo = "****@gmail.com",
    mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
    customReportContent = [ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION],
    resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text
)
```

Comment: but it doesn't send me any data which I was going to send like android version or smth like that :(